# visual studio breaks on handled exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have some code that creates folders on remote shares on our network and im getting an exception due the share not being available.  I'm catching the exception further up the stack just for logging puropses however for some reason vs2010 just stops executing and alerts me to the problem. How can I get it to ignore this exception and let it bubble up.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go to the Debug menu -> Exceptions dialog box in VS and untick the exceptions you don't want to be trapped. You can select an entire range, or individual exception types.

Comment: none of the exceptions are ticked in either thrown or user handled for any exceptions.  I'd already unticked them